# Should I put my mustache template script tags at the bottom of the body like javascript tags?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, mustache

You're supposed to put JS `<script>` tags at the bottom of the body for the best performance. Should I do the same thing for mustache templates?

e.g.

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Awesome Site</h1>
    <div>
      Bunch of stuff...
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="awesome-app.js"></script>

    <!-- should I put this here or does it matter? -->
    <script type="text/html" id="mustache-thing">
      <div>
        {{dynamic_stuff}}
      </div>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**. the principle is the same:

*Allow the browser to load the DOM first and the JS after*

Comment: Why should this matter for `script` tags that have a `type` not interpreted as a script, but as plain data?

Comment: still is plain data that is not needed in front at page load.